# Access variable from another form in Visual Studio with c#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, variables, visual-studio-2013

I'm using c# and Visual Studio. I want to access a variable from another form. I've found some things like:

```
textBox1.Text = form22.textBoxt17.Text;
```

But I don't want to access a textBox value, I just want to access a variable. I've tried this:

```
string myVar1 = Form2.myVar2;
```

But that doesn't work.

Any help?

**Update**
This is what I've got now:

```
        private string _firstName = string.Empty;
        public string firstName
        {
            get
            {
                return _firstName ;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_firstName != value)
                    _firstName = value;
            }
        }
```

In formLogin (where the variable is located), just below `public partial class formLogin : Form`

Then, later in code, inside button on click event:

```
            OleDbCommand command2 = new OleDbCommand();
            command2.Connection = connection;
            command2.CommandText = "select firstName from logindb where username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "' and password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "'";
            firstName = command2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

I write this in formAntonyms (from where I want to access the variable) in formLoad event:

```
        formLogin fli = new formLogin();
        lblName.Text = fli.firstName;
```

The problem with all this is that, when formAntonyms opens, lblName is still empty, instead of showing the users name. What am I doing wrong, I've done all the steps right...

Comment: What exactly _doesn't work_? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path, you should not expose controls or variables directly to client code.

Create a read only property in the form/class you want to read the value from:

```
//Form2.cs
public string MyVar{get{ return textBoxt17.Text;}}
```

Then, being form22 the instance variable of your already loaded Form2 form class. Then, from any client code that has a reference to it, you can read the value of the property:

```
string myVal = frm22.MyVar;
```

**EDIT**:

Ok based in your last comment, you have a variable in Florm1 and want to access it from Form2, the principle is the same as the previous example, but instead of exposing a control property you now expose a private variable, and instead of living in Form2 it now lives in Form1:

```
//Form1.cs
private string _myVar = string.Empty

public string MyVar
 {
    get
    { 
       return _myVar ;
    }
    set
    { 
       if(_myVar != value)
           _myVar = value;
    }
 }
```

The property is now read/write so you can update its value from client code

```
//From From2, assuming you have an instance of Form1 named form1:
string val = form1.MyVar;
...
form1.MyVar = "any";
```

Comment: I get everything until the return textBox17.Text part. But it's my fault, I haven't explained well. I want to access a variable that isn't associated with any txtBox or Label or Button, it's in the code, but it's declared in Form1.cs. And I want to access it from Form2.cs

Comment: I mentioned first code, the one with textBox17 as an example of what I've found here. Everyone's asking how to access value of textBox17, I want to access a variable that isn't displayed any way on the form it was declared and defined.
What should I return in this situation @E-bat

Comment: @StevanMarjanović, see the Edit

Comment: I've provided what I have now.. I don't know what am I doing wrong... @E-Bat

Comment: have you found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is bad object oriented design to access variables from classes directly. It reduces maintainability and reusability.

Your problems arise, because the functionality of your objects is not clear to you.

You should not think in terms of "I want the value of this variable", but in terms of: "Suppose you have a form22, what properties should such a form have?".

Well, apparently it has a size and a position and lots of others, and apparently your form has some information that it displays, and you think that users of this form want to know the text of the displayed information.

Let's suppose the displayed information is named `MyInformation`. Be aware, that you can only display a description of the information. This descriptive text is not the information itself.

A proper object oriented design of your form would be

```
class Form22 : Form
{
    public string MyInformationText {get {return ...; }
    ...
}
```

Now you are communicating to the users of Form22 that a Form22 has some MyInformation. You also communicated that you are not willing to share this information, only to share a descriptive text of the information. Furthermore users of your form can't change this information.

This gives you a lot of advantages. For instance, suppose you don't want to display the text in a TextBox, but in a ComboBox. Or maybe you don't want to display it at all anymore. The users of the form who wanted a descriptive text of MyInformation don't have to change.

Of course your design could be different if you want users of your form to change the information. Probably that would also mean that you need to change the displayed description of your information. But again: users of your form won't need to know this. Again, this gives you the freedom to change it without users having to change:

```
public MyInformation SpecialInformation 
{
     get {return this.mySpecialInformation;}
     set
     {
         this.mySpecialInformation = value;
         this.UpdateDisplay(mySpecialInformation);
     }
}
```

It depends on your model if you should still provide a property for the displayed text or not: Should all MyInformation object in the world have the same displayed text, or could it be that the displayed text in form22 might differ from the displayed text of MyInformation in form23? The answer to this influences whether MyInformation should have a function to get the descriptive text, or whether the forms should have a function to get the descriptive text.

These are just examples to show that you should think in: what should my object do? What should users of my object be capable to do with my objects. The more you allow them to do, the less you will be able to change. You will have the greatest flexibility if you supply them with no more information than required. Besides you'll need to test much less functionality.